Identify board components Yaskawa Z1000 VFD
Is there any way to figure out part numbers for the two components from the picture? That's on board of Yaskawa Z1000 VFD.


Please provide dimensions and circuit info.

Welcome! I modified your title as it hinted to a where-to-buy question, which is off topic here. Your question body was more of an identification question, which is on topic.

The component on top is a 10 kΩ resistor. The one on the bottom is a SMBJ17CA TVS diode made by Diodes Inc.

(Source: lcsc.com)
